# Check, if the current number is lower than the next one | ArgumentOutOfRangeException | C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare a set of numbers of a list. the goal is to check if the current number is lower then the next one.

but i getting a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`  on  the conditional statment.

I would really appreciate your help

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
foreach(var number in input.Split('-'))
{
numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(number));

}
numbers.Sort();

var consecutive = true;

for(var i = 0; i< numbers.Count; i++ )
{
if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1])
{
    consecutive  = false;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Consider when `i` is `numbers.Count - 1`. What do you expect the value of `numbers[i + 1]` to be?

Comment: This is not how your code looks. Please consider formatting your code so it's readable and complete

Comment: For understanding it, I suggest you take a list with 5 items and debug your way through it, and then look what value `i` has in every step, and in which value it throws the exception. Then consider that you can only select items 0,1,2,3 and 4 (because it works zero based). Imagine yourself the list, and ask yourself: until what value of `i` can I get the `I+1` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run the loop for the length of the array. When your current number is the last index of the array, you are going to compare an index out of the range of the array. That means when your current number is the last item of the list, the next number does not exist on the list.

So loop until `array.count - 1`

```cs
for(var i = 0; i< numbers.Count - 1; i++ )
{
    if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1])
    {
         consecutive  = false;
         break;
    }
}
```

Then at the final iteration of the loop `number[i]` is the one before the last item and `number[i+1]` is the last item.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the line:

```
if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1])
```

`i+1` will exceed the collection range when `i` will get to `numbers.Count-1`.